# MySQL - insert into using unknown values

Tags: asp.net, mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert values into a table, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
'BLL.vb
adpUser as new dalUserTableAdapters.tblUserTableAdapter
adpUser.insert(objUser.UserName, objUser,UserPass)
'View.xsd
Insert into User
(UserName, UserPass)
Values
(@UserName, @UserPass)
```

So I need a user to fill in a textbox and the content of the textbox are inserted into the table. All I can find is predefined data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need paranthesis:

```
Insert into User
(UserName, UserPass)
Values
( ? , ? )
```

Try to use `?` instaed of `@parameter`. I think there is difference between trying to connect to SQL-Server and MySQL.

---

And I guess the comma in `objUser,UserPass` is a typo in the post here...

Comment: hmm changed it, but still doesn't seem to do it. Error in values list in INSERT INTO clause.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: Is the above valid ASP.NET code? It doesn't seem like that to me.

Comment: it's just certain bits that are needed for this. Yes, it should be valid code.